# Getting current UTC date with midnight

Tags: date, utc

I need to get the current date in UTC with time as midnight(2017-11-21T00:00:00.000Z).  I am trying to do this with the following code:

```
final ZonedDateTime n = ZonedDateTime.now(Clock.systemUTC());
final String sdate = n.toString();
```

But not able to get the time to midnight?

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks